# Use variable defined in one event in other event

Tags: android

I have one variable declare at the start of the class. Inside the onCreate method I have two Listener. In one I get from a listview one value and assign it to the variable. Then, in the other listener I need to use this variable but it's empty. How can I solve it? Thank you.

```
public class Text extends Activity{
    String option;
    Button btn;
    ListView list;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_telefonos);
        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id){
                option=((Arbitros)a.getAdapter().getItem(position)).getNombre();
            }
        });
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                new asyncarbitros().execute(option);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: You can let your Text class implement each listener and then set your listeners to (this) and do your functionality in those methods on private class variables.

Comment: I couldn't see why it happens. Are you sure you can successfully obtain the value in this line? You should try to print it in a toast message.
"option=((Arbitros)a.getAdapter().getItem(position)).getNombre();"

Comment: @yygyt yes I get the value here.

Comment: @temerariomalaga Can you see the value just before you create the new instance of asyncarbitros? Again you can print a toast message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several different possibilites. The easiest one would be (as @zgc7009 commented) to implement both interfaces (OnClickListener and OnItemClickListener) into your activity. This can be done by simply changing your class declaration to the following line:

```
public class Text extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnItemClickListener
{}
```

In that case you will have to implement the following two methods:

```
public void onClick(View v){...}
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id){...}
```

Alternatively you can create another class that implements the Listeners.

```
public class MyListener implements OnClickListener, OnItemClickListener{
    String option;

    public void onClick(View v){
        option=((Arbitros)a.getAdapter().getItem(position)).getNombre();
    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id){
        new asyncarbitros().execute(option);
    } 
}
```

And you would have to add that Listener to your two Views.

```
MyListener myListener = new MyListener();
list.setOnItemClickListener(myListener);
btn.setOnClickListener(myListener);
```

Hope I could help.

Kind regards

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was having lunch. I try it and now it works. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your text class can implement the listeners directly. For example,

```
public class Text implements extends Activity OnClickListener{
    private String option;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        yourButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onClick(View v){
        option = 5;
    }
}
```

Do the same for on item click listener and you're good. You will be able to use option in your onItemClick method (and likewise for other class/global variables). I will edit a better answer when it's not on my phone :P

Comment: But if I do it, can I execute the android activity? I'm relativement new in android programming

Comment: Isn't there a missing "implements"?

Comment: @temerariomalaga Yep, just replace your part that says .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){... with the new class method and set your listener to the class method using (this). Do that for both listeners.

Comment: @yygyt Yes... Doing this on my cell so it's not complete yet