# How to get the class reference inside an onClick listener in Android?

Tags: android, android-button

I am trying to call this method inside an onClick listener:

```
        mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this,
                SKU_INFINITE_GAS, IabHelper.ITEM_TYPE_SUBS,
                RC_REQUEST, mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);
```

But because it is inside an onClick listener, the reference to this becomes not the reference to the class, but the onClick listener. Is there a way to pass the class reference if this code is inside the onClick listener?

Thanks!

Comment: try using getApplicationContext() instead of this

Comment: this looks like a similar problem that was already posted here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23676634/use-variable-defined-in-one-event-in-other-event/23677099#23677099](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23676634/use-variable-defined-in-one-event-in-other-event/23677099#23677099) I hope it helps Kind regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your containing class is called e.g.MyClass then you can just use MyClass.this:

```
 mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(MyClass.this,
                SKU_INFINITE_GAS, IabHelper.ITEM_TYPE_SUBS,
                RC_REQUEST, mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);
```

Answer (score 2):

Define `Context mContext=null;` in your activity and in oncreate method of activity make instance of this as

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         mContext = this;
}
```

and use

```
mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(mContext,
                    SKU_INFINITE_GAS, IabHelper.ITEM_TYPE_SUBS,
                    RC_REQUEST, mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);
```

or directly use

```
mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(youractivity.this,
                        SKU_INFINITE_GAS, IabHelper.ITEM_TYPE_SUBS,
                        RC_REQUEST, mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);
```

Answer (score 1):

There can be 2 cases

1) If your class extends `Context` eg. `Activity`,`Service` you can do

```
mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(getApplicationContext(),SKU_INFINITE_GAS,IabHelper.ITEM_TYPE_SUBS,RC_REQUEST,mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);
```

2) If your class does not extend `Context` then you need to pass an object of `Context` to that class in some way and call

```
mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(mContext.getApplicationContext(),SKU_INFINITE_GAS,IabHelper.ITEM_TYPE_SUBS,RC_REQUEST,mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);
```

where `mContext` is an object of `Context` class